# When reading on RLHF, I came across this formula but can't break it down

Tags: reinforcement-learning, rlhf

What is the exact meaning of this expression? I'm unsure on the notation.
I believe E[R(s)] is expected value of reward of state s, but I'm unsure what the subscript under the E means.

[image]

Comment: Since it would not be helpful for someone to explain something you already know and understand, can you [edit] to be specific about what part of the notation is unclear to you?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I edited my question

Comment: Great, I think that will help future readers answer this. One more tip is that you can use math typesetting on your posts. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference